# Future returns empty list

Tags: dart, stream, future

I'm new to dart. I'm trying to find the IP address of the TV connected to the wifi network. I'm doing this by first finding all the lan IP address and afterwards making a TV api call to each of the IP address. If I get a valid response back , true is returned. My problem is that the lan ip address list list always comes as empty. If I hardcode it to return some random IP addresses everything works fine. I can also see the addresses it found, so it should not be empty.

I tried switching to a static list, then a normal member list. Got same results back.

```
static getIpAdresses() async {
  String ip = await Wifi.ip;
  final String subnet = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf('.'));
  final int port = 80;
  List<String> lan = new List<String>() ;

  final stream = NetworkAnalyzer.discover(subnet, port);
  stream.listen((NetworkAddress addr) {
    if (addr.exists) { 
      print('Found device: ${addr.ip} ');
      lan.add(addr.ip.toString());
    }
  });
  return lan;
}
```

When using `Network.getIpAdresses().then(( resp) {}` I would expect `resp` to contain a list of the lan IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getIpAdresses` function registers a callback on the stream, but it doesn't *wait* to read anytihing from the stream before returning the local `lan` variable, which at the time is still an empty list.

If you want to wait to read the stream in its entirety, you can use `await for` to iterate on the stream elements:

```dart
static getIpAdresses() async {
  String ip = await Wifi.ip;
  final String subnet = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf('.'));
  final int port = 80;
  List<String> lan = new List<String>() ;

  final stream = NetworkAnalyzer.discover(subnet, port);
  await for (var addr in stream) {
    if (addr.exists) { 
      print('Found device: ${addr.ip} ');
      lan.add(addr.ip.toString());
    }
  }
  return lan;
}
```

See [Asynchronous programming: streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) for more information about using Dart streams and about `await for`.